# JPA: Performance issues due to object relations

Tags: jpa, java-ee-6

I am planning a first Web-App on the basis of Java EE/JPA technology.
I know that JPA maps the object structure of Java classes to a database structure based on the inheritance hierarchies. There are three mapping strategies:

- SINGLE_TABLE
- JOINED
- TABLE_PER_CLASS

An object in Java may have referenced objects, this objects may have further objects referenced and so on. I read that the relationships are defined in the classes by convenient @OneToMany, @ManyToMany, @OneToOne annotations. I can define those relations FetchType either to EAGER or LAZY.

Wouldn't a default EAGER fetch automatically lead to performance issues in a high-grade inheritance structure (which may contain some kind of circles in relationships)? Is there a possibility to limit the level of fetching, e.g. to a deep on X?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot do that in JPA 2.0 (aka EE6). However, in JPA 2.1 (EE 7) you will be able use the new EntityGraph API to define so called fetch plans (see http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

Some JPA providers have provider specific API which offer similar functionality prior to JPA 2.1.

Note that the problem of association fetching is really unrelated to the type of inheritance mapping.